# Z_DATA_ERROR midway through inflate

Tags: c++, zlib, compression, deflate, inflate

I need to decompress some zlib compressed files found within a game's save data. I have no access to the game's source. Each file begins with `0x789C` which tells me that they are indeed compressed with zlib. However, all calls to inflate on these files fail to decompress fully and return `Z_DATA_ERROR`. Using zlib version 1.2.5, 1.2.8, and 1.2.11 with identical results.

Even though zlib is telling me the input data is corrupt, I'm confident that it is not since the game is able to decompress these files with no issues AND this is not isolated to a single data stream. I have **hundreds of thousands** of unique data streams compressed the same way and they all throw a `Z_DATA_ERROR` somewhere in the middle of the decompression.

Furthermore, the partially decompressed data that IS successfully decompressed, is correct. The output is exactly as expected.

Also, about 10% of the time, zlib WILL decompress the entire file, however the result is not correct. Large chunks of the decompressed data contain the same byte repeated over and over, which tells me it was a false positive.

Here's my decompression code:

```
//QByteArray is a Qt wrapper for a char *
QByteArray Compression::DecompressData(QByteArray data)
{
    QByteArray result;

    int ret;
    z_stream strm;
    static const int CHUNK_SIZE = 1;//set to 1 just for debugging
    char out[CHUNK_SIZE];

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
    strm.avail_in = data.size();
    strm.next_in = (Bytef*)(data.data());

    ret = inflateInit2(&strm, -15);
    if (ret != Z_OK)
    {
        qDebug() << "init error" << ret;
        return QByteArray();
    }

    do
    {
        strm.avail_out = CHUNK_SIZE;
        strm.next_out = (Bytef*)(out);

        ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);
        qDebug() << "debugging output: " << ret << QString::number(strm.total_in, 16);//This tells me which input byte caused the failure
        Q_ASSERT(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);

        switch (ret)
        {
        case Z_NEED_DICT:
            ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;
        case Z_DATA_ERROR:
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
            (void)inflateEnd(&strm);
            return result;
        }

        result.append(out, CHUNK_SIZE - strm.avail_out);
    } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

    inflateEnd(&strm);
    return result;
}
```

Here is a pastebin of an example file's data [compressed data](https://pastebin.com/ySSebAZe) with the `0x789C` and trailing CRC removed. I can supply literally endless example files. All of them have the same issue.

Running that data through the above function will decompress the beginning of the stream correctly, but fail on input byte `0x18C`. You can tell it decompressed correctly when the start of the file begins with `0x000B` and the decompressed data is longer than the input data.

I wish I knew more about deflate compression to solve this problem myself. My initial thoughts are that the game has decided to use a custom version of zlib or an extra parameter needs to be given to zlib in order to decompress it correctly. I've asked around and tried many things for days, and I really need someone with knowledge on the subject to weigh in here. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you really want to get to the bottom of this, it might be helpful to provide a larger sampling of savegames, and/or identify the game so other people can produce their own.

Comment: @mwfearnley there are thousands of these compressed files in this single savegame

Comment: Oh, OK.. but it's just the one sample stream you've pasted, right?  Possibly looking at multiple streams would make it possible to find a consistent way that the data is being mangled... Also, I was wondering how you're able to verify the correctness of the partial data?

Comment: I'm able to verify the correctness because I know what to expect in the output. I'm very experienced regarding the save format of this specific game, however it's just this one edition of the game that has different compression. I've attempted to decompress all of the stream in batch. A very very small percentage of them do decompress with no errors, but the data is partially wrong still. I may post all the streams if that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided data is indeed an invalid deflate stream, both with distances too far back, and eight bytes of junk after the deflate stream has ended. There is nothing apparent wrong with your code.

As you noted, at offset 396 there is the first of ten distances too far back. That's where inflate stops. At offset 3472, almost at the end, there is a stored block with a length that doesn't check against its complement.

For the distances too far, you could try setting a dictionary of 32K zero bytes using `inflateSetDictionary()` right after `inflateInit2()`. Then the decompression would proceed, filling in the given locations with zeros. That may or may not be what the game is doing. There is no obvious remedy for the stored-block error.

Indeed the game author's may be deliberately messing with you or anyone trying to decompress their internal data, by having modified zlib for their own use.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Yes I meant offset. I find it interesting that you got beyond byte 396. All other software I've tried this on as well hasn't made it past 396. I'm curious to know if it's also dependent on something else that's in memory at any given time?

Interestingly... in the cases when zlib finished but the output has large chunks of repeated data in spots where there shouldnt be, it's always in the same location. Definitely an indicator to me that it's not just scrambled, but instead a custom compression thing.

Can you tell what customization they used? Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Can you send me the decompressed output you have so I can check it against my expectations?

Comment: My bad -- I missed an earlier error message from my tool. It will stop at 396. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information! You sir are a legend :)

Comment: The 'last block' bit flag is set on the first block (the first octet in the source is an odd number), so there's no block after it - the last 7 bytes are not part of the stream, although the `0f 98 79 17` might be a checksum..  Seems like the only problem is the reads that are too far back.  If the dictionary isn't filled with zeros, you might be able to reconstruct it by comparing those sections with the correct output.

Comment: @mwfearnley Thanks, corrected. There are eight bytes after the end of the deflate stream.

Comment: @MarkAdler you're right, it's 8 bytes - I forgot to discount the need for a second 3-bit block header.